# Buscar igualdades en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Hay 8 salidas y cada una de ellas, se identifica con una letra desde la `A` a la `H`. Cada salida tendrá una variable (`TextBox`) donde el  usuario pondrá solamente números y al terminar de agregar los números, se desea hacer una operación:

Lo ideal es que en todas las salidas tenga un número diferente.

Por ejemplo:

```
Salida      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
variable    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Pero el problema se genera cuando hay números iguales.

```
Salida      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
variable    1   1   2   3   4   5   6   6
```

Por *Visual Studio* es necesario contar las igualdades en este caso `2`, guardar este número y proyectar e identificar las salidas que son iguales, en este caso `A B , G H` y exponerlas.

Las variables, son `TextBox`, y las salidas, son *labels*.

Ejemplo 2:

```
Salida      A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
variable    4   3   2   3   4   5   5   6
```

> igualdades = 3
>   Salidas iguales: AD, BD, FG

[image: interfaz]

Código *VB.NET* (lo que intenté hacer):

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim iguales As Integer
    Private txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim u As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        iguales = 0
        txt = ""

        For i = 1 To 7
            For u = i + 1 To 8
                If Me.Controls("TextBox" & i.ToString).Text = Me.Controls("TextBox" & u.ToString).Text Then
                   // ' U es igual I
                    iguales = iguales + 1
                    txt = txt + u + i + ", "
                End If
            Next
        Next
        txt = RichTextBox1.Text
        iguales = RichTextBox2.Text
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Visual Studio no es un lenguaje de programación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo usaría la función de `GroupBy` de LINQ. Si no estás familiarizado con LINQ, puede que parezca un poco críptico, pero vale la pena aprenderlo.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso, se puede lograr todo lo que quieres en unas pocas líneas de código:

```
Dim valores() = {
    Tuple.Create("a", TextBox1.Text),
    Tuple.Create("b", TextBox2.Text),
    Tuple.Create("c", TextBox3.Text),
    Tuple.Create("d", TextBox4.Text),
    Tuple.Create("e", TextBox5.Text),
    Tuple.Create("f", TextBox6.Text),
    Tuple.Create("g", TextBox7.Text),
    Tuple.Create("h", TextBox8.Text)
}

Dim igualdades = valores _
    .GroupBy(Function(v) v.Item2) _
    .Where(Function(g) g.Count > 1) _
    .ToList

RichTextBox1.Text = igualdades.Count
RichTextBox2.Text = String.Join(", ", igualdades.Select(Function(g) String.Join(String.Empty, g.Select(Function(i) i.Item1))))
```

Aunque no sería razonable dejarte un tutorial completo de como funciona el código, al menos puedo explicar las partes claves.

Con...

```
.GroupBy(Function(v) v.Item2)
```

... se crean grupos de valores idénticos, y con...

```
.Where(Function(g) g.Count > 1)
```

... se filtra la lista de grupos a las que contienen más de un elemento. Estas son las igualdades que buscas.

Luego...

```
igualdades.Count
```

... te da la cantidad de igualdades.

Y finalmente, con una combinación de llamadas a `String.Join()` se puede crear la lista de igualdades separadas por comas.

Answer (score 0):

Un gran amigo me ayudo... pero aun estamos buscando la forma de identificar las letras que son iguales :

```
Public Class Form1
Dim iguales As Integer
Private txt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim u As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim valores() As String = {TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text,
    TextBox5.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox7.Text, TextBox8.Text}

    Dim letras() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"}

    Dim igualdad As String = ""
    Dim cantigualdad As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To 7
        For j As Integer = 0 To 7
            If letras(i) <> letras(j) Then
                If valores(i).ToString = valores(j).ToString Then
                    igualdad = igualdad & letras(i).ToString & letras(j).ToString
                    cantigualdad = cantigualdad + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    RichTextBox1.Text = cantigualdad.ToString() / 2




End Sub
```

End Class